# How can I create a layout for corporate documents using LyX?

Tags: lyx, templates, lyx-layouts

My employer has a layout, current stored as a Microsoft Word template that is used for all sorts of different documents. (There are a few related templates for specific types of documents.) The template has the company logo, a placeholder for the document title and author, and a "version history" table.

My question is how I can reproduce this in LaTeX, with the intention of using LyX as an editor. It doesn't need to be an exact reproduction - e.g. I am happy to use standard LaTeX fonts - but it should be a good approximation.

(I'm using LyX 2.06 with MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7.)

Comment: An image, or at least a schematic, of what it looks like might help people in suggesting a solution

Comment: Thanks @ach but my question is not really "how do I do this for my situation" but "how do I make new templates/layouts in general".

Comment: @AllanLewis If you're up to it, the easiest (i.e. simplest, most common) way to do it is by creating a LaTeX document class and then adding it to LyX through normal means. [(?)](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts)

Comment: As an aside, I would propose to your boss re-thinking the 'version control table' in favor of LyX's [in-house version control integration](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX20#vcs).

Comment: Thanks @SeanAllred, but I think I'm pushing against corporate inertia enough with the change to LyX without having to worry about that as well! In any case, it looks like LyX only supports putting the SVN revision number into the document, whereas we want to retain the incremental version number - 0.1, 0.2, 1.0, etc. If LyX can put SVN tag names into the document automatically, that might work, but otherwise we'll stick to the table I think.

Comment: @SeanAllred OK I saw your second comment first! As for your first comment, that's the type of thing I'd like to do, but I don't know much raw LaTeX. I already found the page you linked to, but like a lot of the LyX wiki, it's a little terse for me! It sounds like there's no way to do this without writing raw LaTeX, in which case I might push for just using the standard "Koma-Script report" class.

Comment: @AllanLewis I'd have to agree from personal experience that LyX documentation is peanuts to LaTeX's.

Comment: Is your problem only about version control, or do you have other issues reproducing the Word template in LyX? If it's the latter, then it might be useful to post an image of the template(s) you're trying to reproduce. On the other hand, it's not likely that LyX can be totally free of raw LaTeX codes anyway. So it might be a good idea to pick up some basic LaTeX. This would also be useful in helping you spot the problem quickly when a `.lyx` document fail to compile.

Comment: Thanks @KevinC - I guess I'd better go learn some LaTeX!

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad: there are lots of things you may have to do, and really from the question we'd be looking at an entire book on how to do it!